# Resolving Google Cloud Platform Bucket Permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set permissions in Google Cloud Platform Bucket Permissions, but when searching using 'storage' for storage.bucket.list, I do not find it. So I am thinking to resolve it to new permission names like "storage legacy bucket reader". So is there a way to know what the old permissions are now named or upgraded to?

I've searched GCP but cannot locate a way to know what the permission names have changed to.

Comment: Hello @wizardbeard, Is the provided solution been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) :

> Some roles may not appear in the bucket permissions window. If you
> grant roles at the project level, they do not appear in the bucket
> permission window, even when users with that role have access to your
> bucket. To view these project-level permissions, go to the IAM & Admin
> screen.

To view the IAM policy for a bucket follow the below steps:

1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Cloud Storage Buckets page.
2. Click the Bucket overflow menu  associated with the bucket whose policy you want to view.
3. Choose Edit access.
4. Expand the desired role to view the principals who have that role.
5. (Optional) Use the search bar to filter your results by role or principal.

   If you search by principal, your results display each role that the principal is granted.

Also refer to the document on [IAM permissions for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions).